# Can not install Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client on windows 10

Tags: qgis, sql-server, installation, windows-10

I am trying to compile QGIS project myself. 
I am following the instructions below, which seems to be official guide but outdated.

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/doc/INSTALL.html#toc15

When I install spatialite library through osgeo4w-setup-x86 : pyspatialite, spatialite, spatialite4dll.
During the install, Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client is required to install but can't proceed because SQL Server 2012 is not supported on the oparting system (Windows 10/7 )

The libraries seems to be installed all right but SQL Server 2012 Native Client.

Is there any workaround to install SQL Server 2012 Native Client.

Eventually I can't do cmake configure to create output.

Comment: Same issue. Did you manage to make progress, or did you give up?
I can install the x64 bit version, though. Did you try that?

Comment: try install the ODBC Driver separately https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339

Answer (score 0):

Probably a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue - is your Win 10 machine x64?  Get the x64 version at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402.  This is a QFE with just the sqlncli.msi files.  It's confusing that they use the same name for both bit architectures.  FYI, this page also says it's supported on Win 10 under System Requirements.